# Passar um objeto entre scenes (telas) JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

A ideia do sistema é salvar algumas informações em um arquivo txt que será consultado por um código em Lisp, será efetuado uma rotina de árvore de decisão e retornará o resultado para ser exibido na interface em Java.

Tenho um objeto que será preenchido em diferentes telas do sistema, minha dúvida é na hora de passar esse objeto pelas scenes. Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

[image: Estrutura do sistema]

A ideia é clicar em um botão na view `Clima` e antes de abrir a próxima view, instanciar `Perfil` e em seguida, chamar a próxima view.

Perfil:

```
public class Perfil {
int clima;
int paisagem;
```

O método que estou utilizando para chamar a próxima view, este será chamado ao clicar no botão da view `Clima`.

```
@FXML
    private void handlePaisagemCalor(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        Perfil perfil= new Perfil();

        perfil.setClima(1);
        perfil.setPaisagem(0);

        Parent climaParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/lisp/view/PaisagemCalor.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(climaParent);
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Comment: Essa é uma das principais desvantagens do FXML, a navegação entre telas. Isso só pode ser resolvido com variáveis estáticas. Sugiro que você abra o gerenciador de tarefas e experimente ficar trocando as telas para ver o impacto no consumo de memória.

Comment: Na verdade pode ser feito usando o construtor da classe controller, a comunicação e intercambio de informação entre duas Scenes pode ser feita desse jeito. Não necessariamente tem que usar variables static

Comment: A classe `FXMLLoader` tem o método `.setController(ControllerClasse)`, use ele para passar o Controller da Scene.

Answer (score 1):

Remova a tag `fx:controller` do seu arquivo fxml (caso esteja utilizando dessa forma). Então instancie o controlador "manualmente" no momento em que for carregar o fxml.

Pelo que eu entendi, você quer passar um objeto `Perfil` para o controlador `PaisagemCalorController`. Assim, a primeira coisa a se fazer é criar um construtor nessa classe de controle para que receba um `Perfil`:

```
class PaisagemCalorController {

    private Perfil perfil;

    public PaisagemCalorController(Perfil perfil){
        this.perfil = perfil;
    }

    /* outros métodos e atributos. */
}
```

Então seu método ficaria assim:

```
@FXML
private void handlePaisagemCalor(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
   Perfil perfil= new Perfil();

   perfil.setClima(1);
   perfil.setPaisagem(0);

   FXMLLoader fxmlloader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/lisp/view/PaisagemCalor.fxml"));
   // Definindo quem é o controller desse 'fxml':
   fxmlloader.setController(new PaisagemCalorController(perfil));

   Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

   // Carregando o fxml na scene:
   stage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlloader.load()));
   stage.show();
}
```